# Password prompt in Roslyn CTP

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, roslyn

I'm working with Roslyn CTP (VS2012) trying to develop a few programs for interfacing with our vendor's Lotus Notes system, and I'm running into a small problem. It's not a progress killer, but since I'm learning how Roslyn works I'd like to find out the answer for the future.

When initializing the Notes Session, I can either enter my password in plain text as an argument to the Initialize method, or I can leave it blank. Below is the actual code I'm using, with a placeholder showing the optional password string.

```
#r "Interop.Domino.dll"
using Domino;
NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
session.Initialize([string pwd]);
```

If I leave it blank, I am prompted to enter the password as if I was using a regular console. However, Roslyn never accepts it. I hit Enter, and the cursor just goes up a line.

CTRL+Enter, Shift+Enter, ALT+Enter - nothing. Esc doesn't abort the password attempt, either. It's simply stuck, with an hour glass. I can't interact with the window at all, just close it or reset it.
If I reset the Roslyn execution engine, then the Notes ID file will be locked and I'll have to reboot to do *anything* with Notes again. Is there a way in Roslyn to respond to a prompt like that? I'd really rather not enter my password in plain text every time.
Here's the actual prompt:

```
[1C2C:0005-172C] The ID file being used is: C:\[Path to ID]
[1C2C:0005-172C] Enter password (press the Esc key to abort):
```

Thanks to any and all who reply!

Comment: You need to show us the code you use for interacting with Notes. It is not clear what you mean by Roslyn never accepts the password.

Comment: I suspect what Scott means here is he's getting the prompt for the password in the Roslyn interactive window, but we're not actually sending the characters across properly.

Scott: are you doing this inside VS or from the command line rcsi?

Comment: Jason - Correct. I get the prompt in the Roslyn window. If I use Python (2.7 or 3.3) via command line (cmd.exe) I get the same prompt. I can enter my password, hit enter, and everything works. Here, I'm starting Roslyn through VS2012 (ctrl-w, i). Sorry for the confusion.
Brian - I _am_ showing you the code. It's the first part I posted - everything I enter into Roslyn to access Lotus Notes. If I enter my password in `session.Initialize()`, it accepts it and I can access the databases. If I don't, I'm getting the password prompt that does nothing.

Comment: Hmm, finally got around to looking at this -- yeah, the current interactive window doesn't support standard input in the interactive window. As a simpler example, just type Console.ReadLine() into the VS Window and watch it get unhappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that IBM takes steps to prevent any rogue processes from trying to spy on or interfere with the password prompt.  (They're pretty serious about security.)  I have no idea what those steps are, but that may be what's causing your problem.

A possible workaround (*for you as a developer, but not recommended for production*) may be to go into your Notes client settings and enable a feature that allows other processes to use your identity without prompting for a password.  This only works if your Notes client is running, but if you're developing applications that talk to Notes this is probably not a big imposition for you.

You haven't said what version of Notes you are using, and the menu picks and wording have changed a few times, so I'll just give the steps for Notes 8.5.

- Select Security on the File menu then select User Security.
- In the User Security dialog, switch to the Security Basics tab.
- Put a check in the box labeled "Don't prompt for a password from other Notes-based programs (reduces security)."

Comment: I can log in using this same method in Python, and I have a GUI tool I wrote a while ago in C# that also works. I only run into problems trying to log with the Roslyn interactive window.

Comment: I don't know anything about Roslyn, so I really can't guess as to what it's doing to break the Notes login.  Have you tried my proposed workaround?

Comment: It's a good workaround and I appreciate your effort, but I'd rather not disable a security feature in favor of enabling another (i.e. not having a plain text pw on my screen). My question is more geared toward "Why won't Roslyn accept the text", and the personal education/growth that would come with the answer, rather than finding a solution to just make it work this one time. If it comes down to it, I'll just switch back to Python as the workaround.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the console input? Interesting problem.